# I need to accept user input immediately upon running my program

Tags: java

First of all, I'm extremely new to Java, so simple answers would be much appreciated.
I'm trying to write a program so that the user can either input the following:

java howManyFiles 10

and get the output:

You selected 10 files.

Or, the user can input the following:

java howManyFiles

and get the output:

How many files would you like?

I can't seem to figure out a way to create a scanner that reads the initial input. The nextLine() scanner method looks for a new user input, rather than checking to see if one already exists. Any help would be a life saver. Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempts and describe in which way they failed. It is called making a [mcve].

Comment: `java howManyFiles 10` seems like `10` is a command-line argument. Those arguments appear in the `String[]` argument to `main`

Comment: This may help: https://www.studytonight.com/java/command-line-argument.php

Comment: I would recommend going through a (decent) textbook, and not relying on some tutorials online. Most of them tend to turn into a "look at what I can code already" show-off. The book will be more structured, and is not as likely to skip quite basic, yet important material.

Answer (score 1):

`java howManyFiles 10` seems like `10` is a command-line argument. Those arguments appear in the `String[]` argument to `main`. Here's a simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        // User didn't provide number of files.
        // You need to prompt the user and read their input.
    } else if (args.length == 1) {
        int numFiles = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("You selected " + numFiles + " files.");
    } else {
        // User provided two or more command-line arguments.
        // You might want to print an error message in this case.
    }
}
```